# I could not find any reference to appear two model simultaneously when AR Marker is scan on AR.JS(A-Frame)

Tags: javascript, augmented-reality, aframe

I have two model and one marker. When scanning the marker, I want two model appear at the same time

Tried to do like this but is not working

`<a-marker type="pattern" url="marker.patt" raycaster="objects: .clickable" emitevents="true" cursor="fuse: false; rayOrigin: mouse;" id="markerA" > <a-entity id="bowser1-model" gltf-model="url(model1.glb)" position="0 0 0" scale="1.6 1.6 1.6" class="clickable" gesture-handler > </a-entity> <a-entity id="bowser2-model" gltf-model="url(model2.glb)" position="0 0 0" scale="1.6 1.6 1.6" class="clickable" gesture-handler > </a-entity> </a-marker>`

Comment: Did you try it with vanilla a-frame without arjs? maybe one of the models is too big, or have its position offset somewhere.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.